# Get package's members without outside modules

Tags: python

I'd like to get list of modules' names in package, but when I run this code:

```
import inspect

modules = inspect.getmembers(mypackage)

for m in modules:
    print(m[0])
```

I get not only "true" members, but also `mypackage` itself, as well as external packages some of the modules rely on - like, for example, `ElementTree` (as `ET`, because it's easier for me to use it like that), `Queue` or `Process` (these are from `multiprocessing`).

*Of course, I also get things like `__builtins__`, `__docs__` and so on, but that's easy to exclude basing on underscores.*

I also found out that when I do

```
import ElementTree as ET
```

in my main script, I can access it then in two different ways - as plain `ET` itself, but also as `mymodule.ET`. I feel this is bad.

**How to avoid that?**

Comment: Do you want a list of a package's submodules, or do you want every attribute of the package that should be considered part of its public API? Note that importing a package generally won't load any of its submodules, so they won't even show up in the `getmembers` output.

Comment: @user2357112: I believe it loads them through `__init__.py`.

Comment: You might look into how `pydoc` does it.

Answer (score 0):

try use this one,bar is your package

```
import pkgutil

import bar

for _, name, ispkg in pkgutil.walk_packages(bar.__path__, "%s." % bar.__name__):
    if not ispkg:
        print(name)
```